# Why a generator object is obtained instead of a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Using Python 3.4, I have the following JSON

```
mylist = [
        {
          "mdata": [
                    {
                      "url" : "http://fake1001/Standard",
                      "fmt" : "Standard"
                    },                            
                    {
                      "url" : "http://fake1001/Thumb",
                      "fmt" : "Thumb"
                    }                                      
                    ]
        },
        {
          "mdata": [
                    {
                      "url" : "http://fake1002/Standard",
                      "fmt" : "Standard"
                    },                            
                    {
                      "url" : "http://fake1002/Large",
                      "fmt" : "Large"
                    }                                      
                    ]
        },
        {
          "mdata": [
                    {
                      "url" : "http://fake1003/Thumb",
                      "fmt" : "Thumb"
                    },                            
                    {
                      "url" : "http://fake1003/Large",
                      "fmt" : "Large"
                    }                                      
                    ]
        }          
      ]
```

I want to put all urls of items with a "Standard" format into a list:

```
urls = []

for m in mylist:
  for md in m["mdata"]:
    if md["fmt"] == "Standard":
      urls.append(md["url"])

print(urls)
```

I get the following result:

```
['http://fake1001/Standard', 'http://fake1002/Standard']
```

Now, I tried using list comprehension to do the same task:

```
urls2 = []
urls2.append(md["url"] for m in mylist for md in m["mdata"] if md["fmt"] == "Standard")

print(urls2)
```

However, I get a generator object instead:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000860F510>]
```

To get the urls, I can call next() on the generator object:

```
print(next(urls2[0]))
print(next(urls2[0]))
```

Which gives me this:

```
http://fake1001/Standard
http://fake1002/Standard
```

What I want to know is why the list comprehension gives a generator object, and if there is any way to avoid that?

Comment: The syntax of the list comprehension involves `[...]`. Also, you can directly do `urls = [...]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) is:

```
(i for i in range(10))
```

You can optionally leave the braces off for functions that take iterables:

```
sum(i for i in range(10))
```

You're probably used to the more common [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[i for i in range(10)]
```

To get a list from a generator simply exahust it with `list()`. In your case:

```
urls2.append(list(md["url"] for m in mylist for md in m["mdata"] if md["fmt"] == "Standard"))
```

Or use a list comprehension instead:

```
urls2.append([md["url"] for m in mylist for md in m["mdata"] if md["fmt"] == "Standard"])
```

Comment: I tried 

`urls2.append([md["url"] for m in mylist for md in m["mdata"] if md["fmt"] == "Standard"])` 

and got this result: 

`[['http://fake1001/Standard', 'http://fake1002/Standard']]`

Hence, I changed it slightly to:

`urls2 = [md["url"] for m in mylist for md in m["mdata"] if md["fmt"] == "Standard"]`

which gives 

`['http://fake1001/Standard', 'http://fake1002/Standard']`

as was needed.