# list comprehension returning "generator object..."

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to succinctly create a list from a dictionary.

The following code works:

```
def main():
    newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key=API_KEY)
    top_headlines = newsapi.get_everything(q="Merkel",language="en")
    news = json.dumps(top_headlines)
    news = json.loads(news)
    articles = []
    for i in news['articles']:
        articles.append(i['title'])
    print(articles)
```

output:

```
['Merkel “Helix Suppressor” Rifle and Merkel Suppressors', 'Angela Merkel', 
 'Merkel says Europe should do more to stop Syria war - Reuters', 
 'Merkel says Europe should do more to stop Syria war - Reuters', 
 'Merkel muss weg! Merkel has to go! Demonstrations in Hamburg', ... , 
 "Bruised 'Queen' Merkel Lives..."]
```

But I've seen elsewhere, and been trying to learn, list comprehension.  Replacing the `for i in news['articles']:` loop with:

```
def main():
    ...
    articles = []
    articles.append(i['title'] for i in news['articles'])
    print(articles)
```

I was expecting to get a similar output. Instead it returns:

```
[<generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x035F9570>]
```

I found [this related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957019/4650297) but doing the following outputs the titles (yay!) three times (boo!):

```
def main():
    ...
    articles = []
    articles.append([i['title'] for x in news for i in news['articles']])
    print(articles)
```

What is the correct way to generate the articles via list comprehension?

<sub><sub>Ignore that I have routines in `main()` instead of calls to functions. I will fix that later.</sub></sub>

Comment: A list comprehension *creates* a list. If you append that list to your list, you don't get the output you want. Instead of appending, just assign the result of the comprehension to your variable.

Comment: `(i['title'] for i in news['articles'])` is a generator expression. Did you mean to pass it to `extend`, rather than `append`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey - Ohh!! That makes perfect sense. It works doing `articles = [i['title'] for i in news['articles']]` :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use:

```
articles = [i['title'] for i in news['article']]
```

The list comprehension already return a list, so there is no need to create an empty one and then append values to it. For a gide on list comprehensions you may check [this one](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

Regarding the generator object, the issue here is that using list comprehensions between `()` (or simply when they are not enclosed) will create a generator instead of a list. For more info on generators and how are they different than lists, see [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) and for generator comprehentions, see [How exactly does a generator comprehension work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work).

Comment: How can I tell the difference in a generator or list comprehension? They look awfully similar to me. (I'll Google around too of course, just wondering if you have a quick way)

Comment: list comprehension are encased in `[ ]`, similar to dicitionary comprehensions are encased in `{ }`

Comment: @BruceWayne A list comprehension is surrounded by brackets (like a list literal). A generator expression uses parentheses instead, and the parentheses can be omitted if the generator is the single argument for a function call (like in `articles.append(i['title'] for i in news['articles'])`).

Comment: @BruceWayne do you understand the difference between lists and generators and the problem is with their comprehensions? Or you do not see clear the differences between these 2 objects?

Comment: @xg.plt.py - I think it's that I don't see the clear differences between them.  I get that a list comprehension is enclosed with `[]`.  I understand the dictionary ones use `{}`.  What I'm not getting (but will, I'm sure, after I look in to your links) is what's a *generator* vs *comprehension*?  Simply leaving `[]` out of a list comprehension creates a generator?  What's the purpose of that, I suppose, is where I'm stuck...?  But I'll read the links, and look around for that stuff.

Comment: @xg.plt.py - Perhaps this helps.  In Matt_G's answer, I don't get why the first is a generator.  It's surrounded with `[]` which made me think it'd be a list comprehension, not generator (*not considering he's using .append()`)

Comment: @BruceWayne 
It produces a list. If it was a generator, you would get append a generator to the list instead of its values. This kind of things are what is explained in the Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension question –

Comment: Reading through it all now, I really appreciate your help! :D

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
articles.append(i['title'] for i in news['articles'])
```

with:

```
articles+=[i['title'] for i in news['articles']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using it in the context you are, produces a generator:

```
 articles.append(i['title'] for x in news for i in news['articles'])
```

Using it like this produces a list:

```
articles = [i['title'] for i in news['articles']]
```

Comment: The first expression produces a list too, not a generator, otherwise, the values would not be appended to articles, but a generator object instead, leaving a list of length 1

Comment: Sorry, grabbed the wrong line of his code. Edited to reflect the correct line)

Comment: In the first example, am I correct in thinking that my `articles` list is being appended with a generator? Could I keep adding strings to that list after or can you not mix types like generator and strings in a list?

Comment: @BruceWayne You can mix strings and generators without problem. In python lists can contain any type of object and in any mixture, each position can contain a different object.